# Зачем нужны статические не вложенные классы?

Tags: классы, java

Зачем нужны статические не вложенные классы?

Answer (score 5):

Для доступа к статическим методам статических классов не требуется создавать экземпляр оных.
Например класс [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).
Если бы метод [`Math.cos()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos-double-) не был статическим, то перед использованием функции косинуса приходилось бы писать:

```
Math mathClass = new Math();
cosinusX = mathClass.cos(x);
```

А так мы обращаемся к методам статического класса `Math` просто по его имени:

```
cosinusX = Math.cos(x)
```

Comment: аналогично для переменных

Comment: Да, кстати, отличный пример статического класса из комплекта Java.

Comment: То, о чём вы говорите, это не "статический класс", а класс, содержащий статические методы. Разные понятия, в Java можно сделать внутренний статический класс, что будет нести определённую семантику.

Comment: с чего вы взяли что java.lang.Math статический???? это методы у него статические!

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что я решил, что Math статический??????
Пример был просто как пример. Я же не говорил что класс Math статический... не так ли??? Я написал: "Если бы метод Math.cos() не был статическим...". Так что вооот.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Статический_класс

Comment: @Nofate, кстати я сам заинтересовался этим вопросом терминологии - и кроме этой статьи в Википедии (без ссылок на АИ, увы) не могу найти упоминания о статических классах (как таковых, что не могут быть инициализированы, имеют только стат. методы и проч.), кроме как в C# - может ли быть, что именно оттуда происходит это понимание статического класса? Или вы использовали его в другой среде?

Comment: На вскидку C# и PHP. Возможно, я не очень удачно спроецировал общие ООП принципы на конкретно их реализацию Java.

Answer (score 2):

Они не нужны, поэтому и создать их нельзя.

**UPD**

По большому счету, все классы верхнего уровня ведут себя, как статические - т.е. вам ничего не нужно создавать перед тем, как инстанцировать их - так что необходимости в этом модификаторе нет и он не просто не поддерживается спецификацией.

Comment: Есть доказательства?

Comment: конечно, вы не сможете скомпилировать `static class A { }`, если он не объявлен внутри другого класса

Comment: просто такая конструкция не поддерживается в java. Однако это не отменяет того факта, что статический класс (как паттерн) в java присутствует. Достаточно написать ненаследуемый класс с закрытым конструктором.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо

Comment: Ну исходя из того, что вопрос именно про "статические *не вложенные*", очевидно, что автор имел ввиду именно возможность объявить внутренний класс статическим, чтобы иметь возможность создавать объекты этого класса без создания объектов внешнего класса, и то, что будет, если объявить не внутренний класс статическим.

Comment: Вообще-то, если трактовать ключевое слово `static` в Java одинаково как по отношению к членам класса, так и по отношению к самим классам, то понятие "статический класс" (опять же, в Java) стоит применять именно к тому классу, который доступен на уровне класса, а не на уровне инстанса: `new Outer.Inner()`, а не `new Outer().new Inner()`. То, что у него внутри не имеет при этом никакого значения.

Answer (score 1):

Статические классы не могут быть созданы на верхнем уровне. Если речь о Static Nested Classes, то ответ [тут](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-static-class-example/) или [тут](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-static-class-tutorial.html). Там же примеры использования. 
Если кратко - статические классы можно создавать без экземпляра класса(enclosing class), в котором он (статический класс) описан. Пример из [доки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
 new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже говорили статические классы верхнего уровня нельзя создавать.
Что касается `nested` классов, то они имеют несколько различий по сравнению с `inner` классами.

1. Объекты данных классов не содержат ссылки на объект класса в котором он находится (`enclosing class`). Соответственно, меньше overhead'а по памяти.
2. Создание объекта `nested` класса не требует объекта `enclosing` класса, т.е. создается только один объект: `new Enclosing.Nested()`